# Get element text content from xml with <break> using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following part from xml file:

```
<database>
<document form='Record'>
<item name='SystemsList'><text>2000;Generl;All equipment<break/>
2001;General;All equipment<break/>
2002;General;All equipment<break/>
2003;General;All Equipment</text></item>
<item name='RmNumber'><text>001</text></item>
<item name='Reason'><text>Don't know</text></item>
<item name='Something'><text>smth</text></item>
</document>
</database>
```

For now I use the following code:

```
Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile1);
            doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList kList1 =doc1.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for(int temp=0;temp<kList1.getLength();temp++)
            {
                Node kNode1=kList1.item(temp);
                //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + kNode.getNodeName());
                if (kNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) kNode1;
            //System.out.println("node name"+eElement.getNodeName());
            Node in=eElement.getFirstChild();
            //System.out.println("__________________"+in.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

            //System.out.println("IN text content----:"+in.getTextContent()+":--------");
            if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("SystemsList")==true)
            {            
                NodeList kList2=in.getChildNodes();
                //if((in.getTextContent()!=null)&&!(in.getTextContent()).isEmpty()&& !(in.getTextContent().length()==0))
                //{
                for(int k=0;k<kList2.getLength();k++)
                {
                    Node kNode2 = kList2.item(k);
                    if((kNode2.getTextContent()!=null)&&!(kNode2.getTextContent()).isEmpty()&& !(kNode2.getTextContent().length()==0))
                        stringBuilder.append(kNode2.getTextContent()+"\n");
                }
                //}
            }
        }
            }
String s=new String(stringBuilder);
        String sa[]=s.split("\n");
        System.out.println("size"+sa.length);
        for(String st:sa)
        {
         System.out.println(st);
        }
```

This code makes the following String=**"2000;General;All equipment2001;General;All equipment2002;General;All equipment2003;General;All Equipment"**.

The question is how can I **get this xml part with break to be ArrayList where each element is 1 line from the xml above or just to make a String array, f/e : SystemsListByYear[0]="2000;Generl;All equipment", SystemsListByYear[1]="2001;Generl;All equipment"** and etc.

P.S. I use the DOM library.

**Edited-question-to-correct**
Edit part:

```
if (kNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) kNode1;
                //System.out.println("node name"+eElement.getNodeName());
                Node in=eElement.getFirstChild();
                //System.out.println("__________________"+in.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

                //System.out.println("IN text content----:"+in.getTextContent()+":--------");
                if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equals("SystemsList")==true)
                {            
                    NodeList kList2=in.getChildNodes();
                    //if((in.getTextContent()!=null)&&!(in.getTextContent()).isEmpty()&& !(in.getTextContent().length()==0))
                    //{
                    for(int k=0;k<kList2.getLength();k++)
                    {
                        Node kNode2 = kList2.item(k);
                        if((kNode2.getTextContent()!=null)&&!(kNode2.getTextContent()).isEmpty()&& !(kNode2.getTextContent().length()==0))
                            stringBuilder.append(kNode2.getTextContent()+"\n");
                    }
                    //}
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Naren nope, I need the code example how to do this.

Comment: Will that xml file will be in that format only... or will it change in this format http://hefaistos.anko.gr:7778/help/wvtxmlex.htm  ..means spacing and formatting ?? Tell me

Comment: @Naren the xml format will stay the same but there can be not 4 elements, but 10: "2001;General;All equipment<break/>
2002;General;All equipment<break/>2001;General;All equipment<break/>
2002;General;All equipment<break/>2001;General;All equipment<break/>
2002;General;All equipment<break/>2001;General;All equipment<break/>
2002;General;All equipment<break/>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this will solve your problem

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "src/file.xml"));
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc1 = builder.parse(fileInputStream);
        doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList kList1 = doc1.getElementsByTagName("item");
        List<String> alist=new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String SystemsListByYear;
        for (int temp = 0; temp < kList1.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node kNode1 = kList1.item(temp);
             System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + kNode1.getNodeName());
            if (kNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) kNode1;
                System.out.println("node name"+eElement.getNodeName());
                Node in=eElement.getFirstChild();
                if((in.getTextContent()!=null)&&!(in.getTextContent()).isEmpty()&& !(in.getTextContent().length()==0))
                stringBuilder.append(in.getTextContent());
                }
        }
        String s=new String(stringBuilder);
        String sa[]=s.split("\n");
        System.out.println("size"+sa.length);
        for(String st:sa)
        {
         System.out.println(st);
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
node nameitem
size4
2000;Generl;All equipment
2001;General;All equipment
2002;General;All equipment
2003;General;All Equipment
```

Comment: I've tried it, but still-same problem I have sa[0]="2000;Generl;All equipment2001;General;All equipment2002;General;All equipment2003;General;All Equipment". May it be because <item> isn't the first element that I have. I have the following xml order : <document><systemList>*everything from example I have in the question*</system List></document>

Comment: please update your question with exact xml so that can give u perfect answer

Comment: @Donvino with above program am getting above output only what u wanted..with your update xml also

Comment: that's strange...my program isn't getting the "\n" or breaks or msth like that when reading <break/>

Comment: @Donvino what ur getting as output tell me ?

Comment: I get everything in 1 line "2000;Generl;All equipment2001;Generl;All equipment2002;Generl;All equipment2003";Generl;All equipment", could it be because of Java version or smth like that? I'm using java 1.7.0_21

Comment: @Donvino why ur using switch there..what is the need.. it is giving compilation error even if i use java 7 also.in which where is case ?In java 6 the switch case only also of int or enum supported.not strings ..why u needed that ..u can use my code as it is

Comment: I use switch to get the exact item with name "SystemsList", I can try to change from switch to if but I don't think it is the problem

Comment: Bthw I've found the problem: my break tag was given me the following way:<break\n> -thats why I couldn't make it. Posted an answer to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Split the text content at `<break/>` and add each split element to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: As I typed This code makes the following String="2000;General;All equipment2001;General;All equipment2002;General;All equipment2003;General;All Equipment"- there is no <break/> tags left in string, that's why I can't split it.

Comment: Have you tried first accessing the children of the `<item>` node?

Comment: Well I thought of that, but may be I did something wrong because it didn't work for me.